# replace java command with custom key word?

Tags: java, user-defined-functions, user-defined-types

I have a method that i'm calling a lot:

`Integer.parseInt(input);`

Is there a way i can take this text and replace with a shorter key word like

`parseInput`

so that i could use it as follows

`month = parseInput`

I've been told that Java does not have #define like C does, but is there no other way at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest thing I can think of to do would be to use the static import feature, which lets you use another class's static methods within your own class, provided you don't break any rules about which methods you can access.  So if you write

```
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
```

at the top of your file, you can then just write

```
month = parseInt(input);
```

when you want to use it.  I can't imagine anything much shorter than that.

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` is static method of Integer class. You can import static classes in your class and use them.

```
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
```

...

```
@Test
public void parseIntTest() throws Exception {
    String val = "10";
    int intVal = parseInt(val);
}
```